# Как клонировать ветку в репозиторий

Tags: git, github

Я нечаянно удалил весь репозиторий, но у меня, можно сказать, есть офлайн копия его. Как мне склонировать ее в мой новый репозиторий?

Comment: переключаешься на нужную ветку и делаешь push

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно заменить URL удаленного репозитория командой:

```
git remote set-url origin NEW_URL
```

Затем вы можете запушить свою локальную ветку в новый удаленный репозиторий:

```
git push origin HEAD:BRANCH_NAME
```